# Different UITabbar buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

My question is about an UITabbarcontroller.
I've an UInavigation controller and an UITabbarcontroller both declared in my Appdelegate. But per I want my tabbar buttons changed When my UIViewController is changed by the NavigationController.

```
 SettingsViewController *sett = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewController1];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.navigationController,sett, nil];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use UINavigationControllerDelegate

```
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

in .h file

then

`self.navigationController.delegate = self;` in .m file

And you detect changing in NavigationController with methods

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Still not working, did what you said and placed the delegate methods in the SettingsViewController but still the two buttons are on my screen, everywhere in my app the same tabbarItems are on the TabbarController.

Comment: @user1113419 Not working what? navigationController didShowViewController method did call when you show new controller. If you need to do something at these time, you need to do it by your own hands in this method.

Comment: This two methods do nothing by themself. But you can inside of them change tabbar buttons like viewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_icon.png"];